# Problem with running NUnit tests Selenium .Net 8 from Command Line (CMD)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nunit-3.0

I am learning automation tests in C# .Net v.8 with Selenium (I'm using ChromeDriver). In Visual Studio Community 2022 all tests are going perfectly, and all are passed. But when I tried to run them in console firstly I was receiving some errors like can't run controller, or some else errors i don't really remember.
Now I'm receiving windows communicate "This program won'w work in your computer. To find version for this computer contact with developer. (screenshot komunikat). After I accept it in console appears
[komunikat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MN0nt.png)
"Access denied".
I turned off antivirus and it's all the same.

Detailed info:

- Windows 11 Pro,
- Chrome v. 120
- Visual Studio Community 2022
- .Net v. 8.0
- installed packages:

  - coverlet.collector 6.0
  - Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk v. 17.8
  - NUnit 4.0.1
  - NUnit Analyzers 3.10
  - NUnit.ConsoleRunner 3.16.3
  - NUnit3TestAdapter 4.5
  - Selenium Support 4.16.2
  - Selenium.WebDriver 4.16.2
  - Selenium.Webdriver.Chrome 120
    All installed from VS in NuGet Menager. After this in VS i'm locating Nunit.ConsoleRunner, I click RMB on it and choose "show in explorer". Then i copy path and through console (admin) i navigate to this destination then i write NUnit3.Console.exe "path to my project>bin>debug>.net8>and pick the file with project name and .dll.

I am searching for answer for ages in web, problem is my course is from 2017, so pretty old. I cant find solution by myself, and don't have a clue what the heck is wrong... I tried reinstall but all the same.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: First check compatybility for NUnit ConsoleRunner 3.16.3 -> NUnit 4.0.1, Im not sure, but you should use lower version of NUnit like 3.x.x.